# Find the owner of a file in unix

Tags: unix

Is there a way to get just the file's owner and group, separated by space in unix shell?

I'm trying to write a script to find the owner of all the files in a directory and print it (in a specific format, can't use `ls -la`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
ls -l | awk '{print $3, $4 }'
```

That'll do it

Comment: You can add |sort |uniq if you only want the distinct users/groups rather than a long list with duplicate

Comment: the tr was just my fingers twitching out of habit - it orders them by time, reversed

Comment: What does: -l mean. What does awk mean, etc. etc.

Answer (score 14):

Use the `stat` command, if available on your version of UNIX:

```
    $ stat -c "%U %G" /etc/passwd
    root root
```

or, to do this operation for all files in a directory and print the name of each file too:

```
    $ stat -c "%n %U %G" *
```

Comment: WARNING: "stat" returns the string "UNKNOWN" for %U and %G if it is not defined in the system files. While "ls" will return the UID/GID if unknown. It is better to work with UID (%u) and GID (%g) numbers from "stat" if possible.

Answer (score 3):

GNU find has the -printf option which will do this for you:

```
# if you want just the files in the directory, no recursion
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%u %g\n"

# if you want all the files from here down 
find "$dir" -type f -printf "%u %g\n"

# if you need the filename as well for disambiguation, stick a %f in there
find "$dir" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%u %g %f\n"
```

Other systems might have this as gfind.

Comment: read user group < <(find "$dir" -prune -printf "%u %g\n")

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -l | cut -f3,4 -d" " | tail -n +2
```